# Delete from text file bad characters

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Hello yesterday i did combine multiple text files into one
So when i've opened the combined result.txt i saw lot of bad characters
My guess i forgot to delete some zip rar files and those was combined into the output file
So i got a result like this is there a way to delete all those bad characters from the result.txt
Using awk or sed ??
[image]

Comment: Maybe `strings file.txt` will be sufficient?

Comment: @SamJ : Use `tr` with the `-d` option, if you can define exactly, which characters should be deleted and which ones should stay in plaxe.

Comment: `sed 's/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]//g' file > newfile`

Comment: `grep -Pv "[\x80-\xFF]"` ?  This would delete all lines with non-ASCII bytes.